# List all Keybindings for a certain emacs mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I know that I can list all the keybindings available in emacs by using C-h b, but is it possible to list only the keybindings that apply to a certain mode, say dired-mode.

In dired+, I can do

```
?
h
```

and it shows me all the applicable dired mode keybindings.

Thanks

Answer (score 60, accepted):

use `C-h m` or `M-x describe-mode`

Comment: M-x describe-minor-mode for a particular minor mode.

Answer (score 21):

Not sure what the question is. <kbd>C-h b</kbd> shows you all of the key bindings currently available (i.e., in the current mode).

If you want to see only the key bindings provided by a mode's own keymap, then use library `help-fns+.el` and hit <kbd>C-h M-k</kbd>. You are prompted for the keymap variable (e.g. `dired-mode-map`).

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/help-fns%2b.el